# Нужно добавить несколько списков в один, но в reverse состоянии

Tags: python

```
def data_reverse(data):
    
    chunk_size = 8

    splitted_list = list()

    for i in range(0, len(data), chunk_size):
        a = data[i:i+chunk_size]
        splitted_list.append(a)
    b = splitted_list[::-1]
    print()

data_reverse([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16])
```

Есть такой код. Нужно чтобы массив делился на несколько массивов по 8 элементов. Но должны быть в reverse.То есть [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16] => [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]] => [[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]] => [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
P.S без библиотек

Comment: А проблема у вас какая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое решение. Единственный трюк это `range(...)[::-1]`. Можно написать `reversed(range(...))`:

```
def data_reverse(data, chunk_size=8):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(data), chunk_size)[::-1]:
        result.extend(data[i:i + chunk_size])
    return result
```

Comment: спасибо помогло

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, этот код Вам поможет

```
chuck_size = 8

def list_swap(my_list : list, chank_size : int) -> list:
    func_list = my_list.copy()
    new_list = []
    last_i = 0
    for i in range(chank_size,len(my_list),chank_size):
        new_list.append(func_list[last_i:i])
        last_i = i
    else:
        new_list.append(func_list[i:len(my_list)])
    func_list = []
    for i in range(len(new_list)-1, -1,-1):
        func_list.extend(new_list[i])
    return func_list

test = list_swap([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17], chuck_size)
print(test)
```

Объясняю:

```
func_list = my_list.copy()
```

Копирую старый список, чтобы ничего случайно там не изменить (тк список ссылочный тип)

```
for i in range(chank_size,len(my_list),chank_size):
        new_list.append(func_list[last_i:i])
        last_i = i
```

Разбиваю список на подсписки размером `chank_size`

```
else:
    new_list.append(func_list[i:len(my_list)])
```

После цикла додобавляю лишние элементы

```
   for i in range(len(new_list)-1, -1,-1):
        func_list.extend(new_list[i])
```

Просто записываю элементы списка в обратном порядке. Заметьте, я использую для этого `extend`, чтобы в итоге получился единый список без подсписков

В конце просто `возвращаю` получившийся список

Comment: `for/else` не к месту.

Comment: Ещё приём: `range(len(new_list)-1, -1,-1)` -> `range(len(new_list))[::-1]`. Ещё лучше так `for v in reversed(new_list): func_list.extend(v)`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy А `reversed` над списком достаточно лениво работает, ничего лишнего не создаёт? `range(...)[::-1]` мне кажется заведомо плохо, хотя может срез тоже ленивый? Сам то `range` максимально ленивый объект.

Comment: @CrazyElf, `range(...)[::-1]` - это снова `range`. `range(0, 10, 2)[::-1]` -> `range(8, -2, -2)`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Крутая оптимизация, не знал ))  Тогда да, тогда это хорошо

Answer (score 0):

Можно куски массива просто записать в обратном порядке

```
def data_reverse(data, chunk_size):
    splitted_list = list()
    for i in range(0, len(data), chunk_size):
        a = data[i:i + chunk_size]
        splitted_list = a + splitted_list
    return splitted_list


print(data_reverse([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], 8))

# [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Квадратичная сложность получилась.

Answer (score 0):

Рекурсивный вариант

```
def data_reverse(lst, size=8):
    return data_reverse(lst[size:], size) + lst[:size] if len(lst) > size else lst

print(data_reverse(list(range(1, 17))))
```

```
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо, поправил. Сработал стереотип :)

Comment: Задачка: сможете ли вы написать рекурсивную функцию с линейной сложностью? :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy могу ошибаться, но, по-моему, этот код O(N). Если не так, прошу пояснить, в чем подвох.

Comment: Каждый `+` копирует оба своих аргумента. Сложность `sum(len(lst) + (len(lst) - size) + (len(lst) - 2 * size) + ...). Квадрат.